# IndexError: list index out of range for parsing script

Tags: python, windows, parsing, indexing

newbie here so please forgive my uncertainty.

I am trying to create a script which pings IP address' a file called ARPips.prn, while parsing the output so I can later create graphs for results over time. I have been researching this problem on this website and others and I cant apply the possible solutions to my case.

Here is my script:

```
def ping2():

    plat = platform.system()

    with open( 'C:\Python26\ARPips.prn', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            #while True:

                if plat == "Windows":
                    pingArgs = ["ping", "-n", "1", "-l", "1", "-w", "100", line]
                elif plat == "Linux":
                    pingArgs = ["ping", "-c", "1", "-l", "1", "-s", "1", "-W", "1"]
                else:
                    raise ValueError("Unknown platform")

                ping = subprocess.Popen(pingArgs,
                    stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                    stderr = subprocess.PIPE,
                    shell=True)

                out, error = ping.communicate()

                print out

                lost = int(re.findall(r"Lost = (\d+)", out)[0])
                min = int(re.findall(r"Minimum = (\d+)", out)[0])
                max = int(re.findall(r"max = (\d+)", out)[0])
                print "Packet loss = %s" % lost
                print "Maximum = %s" % max
                print "Minimum = %s" % min

                x = line.split(";")
                if len(x) < 14:
                    continue
                else:
                    print"Invalid line l =", x
```

The output I get is as follows:

```
Pinging 10.10.10.1 with 1 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.10.10.1: bytes = 1, time = 3 ms, TTL=255

Ping statistics for 10.10.10.1:
    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milliseconds:
    Minimum = 3ms, Maximum = 3ms, Average = 3ms

Packet loss = 0
Maximum = 3
Minimum = 3

Pinging 10.10.10.41 with 1 bytes of data:
Request timed out

Ping statistics for 10.10.10.41:
    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 0, Lost = 1 (100% loss),
```

The error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Python26\ScapyScripts\main.py", line 114, in ping2
    min = int(re.findall(r"Minimum = (\d+)", out)[0])
  IndexError: list index out of range
```

Now if I comment out the following lines:

```
min = int(re.findall(r"Minimum = (\d+)", out)[0])
max = int(re.findall(r"max = (\d+)", out)[0])
print "Maximum = %s" % max
print "Minimum = %s" % min
```

The error disappears and the code runs fine. I'd be really grateful if anybody could help me out with this! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression isn't matching, so `re.findall()` returned an empty list:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r"Minimum = (\d+)", 'No such minimum')
[]
```

Without seeing the exact output of the `ping` command you are running, it is hard to say *why* the regular expression isn't matching.

Comment: First of all thanks for looking at this, I really appreciate your help!

I've added the output to my question, what do you think?

Comment: Thanks! 

The problem was as you said, by changing this line:

 min = int(re.findall(r"Minimum = (\d+)", out)[0])

to this line:

re.findall(r"Minimum = (\d+)", out)

Thanks again! :D